# Inno Setup doesn't install service on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: c#, service, inno-setup

There is a service, I wrote on Visual Studio 2012(C#). And I want Inno setup to install it.
I've add in Inno setup this script:

```
[Run]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "create ""FBA Service"" binPath=""{app}\FBA_Service.exe"""; WorkingDir: {sys}; StatusMsg: "Install Service"; Flags: ShellExec RunHidden;
```

On Windows 8, this works OK.
But on Windows 7 64bit, it doesn't install my service.
Help please, I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use installutil which locates in the .NET Framework installation folder,

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\v2.0. or v4.0.***

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984379%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: But sc.exe on win7 install my service without any promblems

Comment: Maybe it is caused by the bitness (64 bit OS). When you launch a prompt from Start menu, the 64 bit sc is called. Inno Setup always runs as a 32 bit process, so it may launch 32 bit sc.

Comment: I create AnyCPU project, but when this happen,  i also created x86 project, and it also didn't install

Comment: It has nothing to do with your project. Your project should always be AnyCPU. It is the setup.exe generated by Inno Setup generated that is available only in 32 bit. If you use installutil, it is capable of handling the bitness issue for you, and that's why I suggest it.

Comment: Thanks, this script works:`[Run]
Filename: {dotnet20}\installutil.exe; Parameters: FBA_Service.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: "Service install"; Flags: ShellExec RunHidden;

[UninstallRun]
Filename: {dotnet20}\installutil.exe; Parameters: "/u FBA_Service.exe"; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: "Service install"; Flags: ShellExec RunHidden;`

Comment: but it is interestin why on Win8 x64 , sc.exe works, but on win7 x64 it didn't

Comment: You might use SysInternals tools to check what exactly happens under the hood (process explorer and process monitor) if you are interested in locating the culprit.